# Why is GHC not importing Semigroup ((<>))

Tags: haskell

I've been given code by my lecturer that doesn't build in GHCI. As far as I know, it has been building correctly for my classmates.

The code I'm refering to is

```hs
import Data.Semigroup  (Semigroup ((<>)))
```

GHCI is throwing this error at me

```
Module ‘Data.Semigroup’ does not export ‘Semigroup((<>))’
```

Should this work? Is there perhaps something wrong with my version of GHC? All other import statements are working.

Comment: Locally this works. What ghc version do you use?

Comment: @thatotherguy not really; prior to GHC-8 the `Data.Semigroup` module was not in the `base` package but that would give a different error. With the `semigroups` package installed, the behaviour should be the same.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm currently running 7.10.3. I'll try updating it?

Comment: Eeep, yeah that's ancient.  GHC isn't like gcc, the open source packages and community assume you're within 3 releases of the latest.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson but why does it give that error message and not `Could not find module ‘Data.Semigroup’`? Or if `semigroups` is installed, why does it not just work?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Not sure why you'd ask me but... likely because it _could_ find the module Data.Semigroup.  Don't forget `Data.Semigroup` was a module in non-base packages for a while before base finally tamed things.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson of course, but then the import should have worked just fine.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Not at all, the `semigroup` package has a module `Data.Semigroup` but it does not have export a symbol `(<>)`.  It probably isn't alone.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson The `semigroup` package doesn't exist on Hackage as far as I can tell. The `semigroups` package does exist, but for every version I could be bothered to check, its `Data.Semigroup`, if it exists at all (CPP is used to prevent it from existing on newer GHCs), exports the symbol `(<>)`. So what gives?

Comment: @danielwagner what gives? Searching is hard, let's go linking: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Semigroup-0.0.7/docs/Data-Semigroup.html

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Phew! Nice find.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I don't know how you found that archaeological piece of documentation, but I really would like to read that comment before... hahaha, I was losing my mind trying to find in which version of ghc I could reproduce the error

Comment: @leftaroundabout it turns out that the ghc version that is using should be `0.0.7`, is the only explanaition

Comment: @DamianLattenero actually more like GHC-6.12 / base-4.2 (from 2010, which is the time of the `Semigroup` package). Still, I'd say “archaeological document” is a fair description! Do you want to integrate this in your (already great) answer, or should I write it up as Community Wiki?

Comment: @leftaroundabout fantastic! Yes I can add it of course! And can you also write a Community wiki? I don't know if it can be both things, I don't have much knowledge about community wiki to be honest

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem locally works depending on the ghc version, your question is the key in this issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Final Edit**

> Is there perhaps something wrong with my version of GHC?

Absolutely yes, there is something wrong, is too old, to be precise:

`GHC-6.12 / base-4.2` (from 2010, which is the time of the Semigroup package) -- thanks so much @leftaroundabout and @Thomas M. DuBuisson for the contribution!

And that package has not the `(Semigroup ((<>)))` function. Hence the error you see.

> Edit 2

After comments, I tried to reproduce the OP environment to reproduce the error too, I installed in stack the ghc version `7.10.3`, this is how looks the stack.yaml file:

```
resolver: lts-6.27 
system-ghc: false
packages:
- .
```

And after ruining a base stack project with a Main.hs file containing:

```
module Main where

import Data.Semigroup

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello"
  putStrLn "World"
```

the error I got is

```
/home/damian/test-semigroup/app/Main.hs:3:8:
```

> Could not find module ‘Data.Semigroup’

```
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.    
--  While building package test-semigroup-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/damian/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.22.5.0_ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:test-semigroup exe:test-semigroup-exe --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

The same happend with older versions:

- LTS 3.22 for ghc-7.10.2,

I couldt try with:

- LTS 2.22 for ghc-7.8.4, published 4 years ago
  Because they where to old to run with cabal

and
 - LTS 0.7 for ghc-7.8.3, published 5 years ago
Because they I cannot install it in a 64bit OS...

So, to be absolutely sure I tried with all the newer LTS versions one by one, yes... one by one, It took some time but worth the shot:

- LTS 13.29 for ghc-8.6.5, published today
- LTS 13.19 for ghc-8.6.4, published 3 months ago
- LTS 13.11 for ghc-8.6.3, published 4 months ago
- LTS 12.26 for ghc-8.4.4, published 7 months ago
- LTS 12.14 for ghc-8.4.3, published 9 months ago
- LTS 11.22 for ghc-8.2.2, published 11 months ago
- LTS 9.21  for ghc-8.0.2, published a year ago
- LTS 7.24  for ghc-8.0.1, published 2 years ago

None of those ghc version could reproduce your log error, so I thought to try a typo maybe:

```
import Data.Semigroup (Semigroup ((<$>)))
```

or

```
import Data.Semigroup (Semigroup ((=>>)))
```

And those gave me your error:

/home/damian/test-semigroup/app/Main.hs:3:24: error:

> **Module ‘Data.Semigroup’ does not export ‘Semigroup(())’**

1. That means, that the `Data.Semigroup` module exists in your `ghc`
2. `Semigroup((<>))` is not part of that module

Meaning, you must have one of the oldest `ghc` versions...

So, I just can think that you can try:

- Reinstall your ghc, and try it to run it again.
- Please, consider using some tool such as [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/)
- Check your code, look out for some typos or something odd

I stand that my first answer was close though:

> Edit 1

It has been added in **ghc version `8.0.1`**

A quick search in hoogle always helps:

[Here](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%3E&scope=set%3Astackage) first link is semigroup <>, `(<>) :: Semigroup a => a -> a -> a`

and it says:

[image]

This versions is able since May 2016, and it ghc version is `8.0.1`.

To see all versions of ghc with its base versions:

https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package

Answer (score 4):

ThomasM.DuBuisson found what must have been the problem (discussion in comments): there are three different packages defining a `Data.Semigroup` module –

- [`base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html). As of GHC-8, Haskell ships with the semigroup class and -module out of the box, so you don't need to take care for anything. See [Damian Lattenero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57119287/745903) for details.
- [`semigroups`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-Semigroup.html). In GHC-7, there was no semigroups class in `base` but the `semigroups` package was semi-official part of the base libraries. In fact, this exact module was just copied over to `base`. The way to write really backwards-compatible code with semigroups is still to depend on the `semigroups` package: when compiling against new GHC versions, that package just uses the `base` module, only in old versions does it provide the module itself. See [the `.cabal` configuration](https://github.com/ekmett/semigroups/blob/a54abc71ccb538e9ffd422403bd58ffbf7dd5cf0/semigroups.cabal#L137)

  ```
    if impl(ghc < 7.11.20151002)
      -- starting with GHC 8 these modules are provided by `base`
      hs-source-dirs: src-ghc7
      exposed-modules:
        Data.Semigroup
        Data.List.NonEmpty
  ```
- `Semigroup` is an obsolete package back from 2010. It too exports [a `Data.Semigroup` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Semigroup-0.0.3/docs/Data-Semigroup.html), but unlike the `semigroups` one this is *not* compatible with the official `base` module. It does have a `Semigroups` class, but its method is called `.++.` rather than `<>` (probably, to not clash with the operator from `Data.Monoid` – that is by now not an issue, because in very new versions [`<>` is now in the prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--62-) and already works on semigroups).

So, what happened for you is probably the following:

1. You tried to compile your code
2. GHC complained `Could not find module ‘Data.Semigroup’`. That's because you're running an old compiler.
3. At this point, what you should have done would be installing/depending on the `semigroups` package. Instead you installed the `Semigroup` package, which is unfortunately incompatible.

There are two solutions:

- Use Cabal-install and allow for your old compiler. IMO this is *ok*, though you should be prepared to run into other dependency troubles in the future. If you do this, you need to add the `semigroups` package in the `build-depends` of your `.cabal` file.
- Or use Stack to enforce a recent compiler. Select e.g. `lts-12.14`.